# Texture stretching at edge even though UV map says it's fine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, edges

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I'm still new and following this anvil tutorial but the texture is stretching  over one edge and also sort of looks like I've put a seam where I haven't. It's fine on the other side and both sides are clean blue in the UV map on the right where the edge is selected

Bad side
[image: Bad Side]
Good side
[image: Good Side]

Answer (score 0):

The distortion in your unwrap may be caused by:

- modifier options: some modifiers (e.g. solidify) can add som distortion to your unwrap
- geometry errors: for example duplicated vertices or overlapping faces
- uvs are not relaxed enough

So, first of all check your geometry. If your model is perfect, then you have two options:

- unwrap again the faces which have the distortion
- pin the borders of your shells and update the uv coordinates (a pinned vertex will keep it's position also if you try to unwrap the entire model)

I would suggest to apply the last option, and to do that:

1. in **UV/Image Editor** select the border edges of your shells and press **P** to pin these vertices (now are red colored)
   [image]
2. select all the shells (with **A** for example) and then press **E**, so you will update the uv coordinates for all vertices except the pinned ones
   [image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying but unfortunately after trying all your suggestions the weird distortion is still there, assuming I did them right. I did manage to fix it by deleting half and using the mirror modifier again, not a great fix which is why I didn't put it as an answer but at least it worked